# Sort List<Object> by other List

Tags: java, list

I have a Manager object.

```
public class Managers{
    ...
    private String taxCode;
    ...
    (Constructors, Getters)
}
```

I have `List<Managers> managers` and `List<String> taxCodes`.

How to sort objects in managers according to taxCodes order in List taxCodes?

Comment: Do they have the same length? Does taxCodes[0] belongs to managers[0]?

Comment: `managers.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(mgr -> taxCodes.indexOf(mgr.getTaxCode()));`